# Hall-Littlewood polynomials of non-dominant weights

Tags: ag.algebraic-geometry, rt.representation-theory, lie-groups, kt.k-theory-and-homology, symmetric-functions

$\DeclareMathOperator\SL{SL}$Let $\lambda = (\lambda_1,\ldots,\lambda_n)$ be a sequence of positive integers and let
$$
R_\lambda(x;t) = \sum_{w\in S_n} w\cdot \left( x_1^{\lambda_1}\ldots x_n^{\lambda_n} \prod_{i<j}\frac{x_i - tx_j}{x_i - x_j}\right).
$$
If $\lambda$ is dominant, i.e. $\lambda_i\geq \lambda_{i+1}$, then $R_\lambda$ is (up to a scalar in $\mathbb{Q}(t)$) the Hall-Littlewood polynomial associated to $\lambda$. The polynomials $R_\lambda$, for $\lambda$ dominant, are a basis for symmetric polynomials over $\mathbb{Q}(t)$.

Now, if $\lambda$ is arbitrary, $R_\lambda$ will still be a symmetric polynomial over $\mathbb{Q}(t)$, so there should exist coefficients $A^{\lambda}_{\mu}(t)$ such that
$$
R_\lambda = \sum_{\mu \textrm{ dominant}} A^{\lambda}_{\mu}(t)R_{\mu}.
$$

When $t=0$: the polynomial $R_\lambda(x;0)$ is in any case an equivariant Euler characteristic of the line bundle $\SL_n\mathbb{C}\times^B \mathbb{C}_{-\lambda}$ on the flag variety $\SL_n\mathbb{C}/B$, and by the Borel-Weil-Bott theorem it can be seen that
$$
A^{\lambda}_{\mu}(0) = \begin{cases} (-1)^{l(w)} &\mbox{if } w(\lambda+\rho)-\rho = \mu, \\ 
0 & \mbox{otherwise. }  \end{cases}
$$

Otherwise, though, it seems like they might be more complicated. Are these coefficients already calculated somewhere?

Comment: The q in the first equation should be t? In any case, at t=0, they are Schur polynomials, and Schur polynomials indexed by compositions are computed via the Jacobi-Trudi identity. What you get in that case, is a Schur polynomial (up to a sign), or 0. Perhaps something similar happens in the Hall-Littlewood case, but I am not sure.

Comment: @PerAlexandersson: your statement about Schur polynomials indexed by compositions is equivalent to the formula for $A_\mu^\lambda(0)$ in the question.

Comment: Here is one example: $R_{(1,2)} =(t^3-1)R_{(1,1,1)}+tR_{(2,1)}$.